# is it possible to acquire radio tower information and cellular strength to triangulate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, location

I just want to know if objective c got any api for us to acquire the nearby radio towers information and the respective radio strength received of it. Using these information to triangulate the iphone will be more accurate than only using GPS/CLLocationManager?

or the CLLocationManager has already triangulated the phone and return the calculated location of the iphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLLocationManager already gets the location based on GPS, Radio towers, etc...

You cannot access radio tower data yourself.

Comment: Thanks! But what about using non-official api? are there any private api can get those information?

Comment: Then you get the risk of your app being rejected, I wouldn't do it